# Can I get the BIOS date and time?

Tags: vbscript

I have a script, which monitors some folder's subfolders, check their created date, and if  DateDiff from created time and Now is more than 730(2 years) it deletes this folders. The problem is in that, if set current time on PC for 5/16/2015 - the script will delete folders, and it's not cool. I thought about getting time from some internet service, but there is no guarantee that PC will be connected to internet. So I tried to get BIOS time (I believe no users can change it to wrong), and compare folder's created time with this time. But, unfortunately I didn't find the way how to do that. Maybe you have any idea how to implement this task?

Comment: You have to trust time from *somewhere* to do a date calc.  Your choices are the local system (I can easily change the BIOS date as well as the Windows date) or from a remote source (as you mentioned, may not have internet access).  Ultimately, doing any date calculations is vulnerable to someone messing with the clock.

Comment: A man says to his doctor: "It hurts when I do this". The doctor replies " Well, don't do that, then". Seriously, have you thought about _not_ setting the time to 2015?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having an incorrect date and time on a production-level machine is not an option nowadays. It will break a lot of things like HTTPS sites (they will fail to validate because of expired certificates), etc.

The system clock (BIOS time) is changed by the operating system whenever the time itself is changed in the OS, so you only have one clock in the computer. In other words the OS does not have a separate clock to track time with.

Nowadays most computers use the [Network Time Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) to keep their clocks in sync, so **you should specify the correctly set time as a pre-requisite for your software**. (Or you can just specify that the computer must be connected to an external atomic clock, but that's going to be expensive.)

Comment: This. Especially the middle paragraph. But all of it, really. +1